# few questions about the ezybox 24"

Tags: studio-lighting, softbox

I have a t3i and bought a pair of yn-622c and I wanted to buy a 430ex ii as well as a lastolite ezybox softbox 24x24".

1. I've read that the flash + yn combo might be too high in order to point the flash directly to the hole in the softbox, is that right?
2. I've also heard that this flash will be too weak for some uses because of the size of the softbox. Any opinions about that?
3. I have 60 +/- cm of space in my suitcase for a light stand. I was looking at the manfrotto 1004bac but its way too large to fit in there, so Im thinking about the 1051bac or 1052 (I have a manfrotto tripod and I love it, so I'm kinda locked on manfrotto, but I'm open to other brands). Will the 1051/2 be strong enough to hold a softbox + speedlight + trigger outdoors (light wind, not anything major)?

thats about it. Is there anything else I need to know?
thanks in advance

Comment: thanks for the editing patrick. I tryed writing the whole thing like that but somehow it ended up without spaces and such. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1) Even if it doesn't fit directly, you could use a hotshoe cable to hook up to it to fix the mount position problem.  They also have a shot with a pocket-wizard working with a 580EXII, so I don't think that it would be a problem even directly mounted.

2) The 430EX is certainly less powerful than the 600EX or 580EXII.  I've not personally tried it with a softbox of that size, but I know the next 320EX is nowhere even approaching powerful enough for that size softbox unless it is pretty dim.  The amount of light you need is always going to be a factor.  Your best bet when researching this is to look at the number of stops of light that you lose (should be available from the softbox manufacturer) and compare it with the output power of the flash to see if it is enough for your situation.

UPDATE: It seems that it is difficult to find information on the stops of loss that you get when using any of the Ezybox soft-boxes.  The best I could find was a claim on a forum that said that Ezybox claims that they only lose half an EV, which is pretty darn good if true.

3) I have a Manfrotto Nano stand and it is pretty good.  The 1052 is going to be even more sturdy.  The one thing you will need to do with a softbox in light wind though is to use sand bags.  Light stands are not tripods, they spread out quick at the bottom and extend up a long way.  They need to be weighted down when they have a big sail on top of them.

Comment: thank you! so, DO I NEED THE 600? IM STILL NOT GETTING A DEFENITIVE DECISION

Comment: @User13074 - without knowing your exact shooting situation and light requirements, there is no way to tell.  If you are shooting indoors in a dark or moderately lit room, you will probably be ok.  If you need to be outside in bright sunlight and compete with direct sunlight from 20 feet away, you are probably out of luck with either the 430 or the 600.  You need to do basic lighting requirement calculations and use the max output power for the flash, subtract .5 EV and see if it is still enough power for your situations.

Comment: I want to photograph subject in shade and a sun-lit background, or sometimes use the sun as a rim light from the back.              I've watched chase jarvis's video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bc2nY6l5cGw , but he was probably using big strobes or something big and expensive...

Comment: @User13074 - how close will you be able to place the light though?  The closer you get, the less power you need.  Light power falls off rapidly, particularly when covering a larger area with light (which is going to be a result of using such a large diffuser).  It looks like the 430EX II is roughly 50% more powerful than the 320EX and is 1/4 less powerful than the 600EX.  It has a 14mm guide number at ISO 100 of 31 feet.  Factoring in the loss of power from the softbox, you'll probably be ok within 10 feet if they are in the shade and my understanding is correct, but that's an approximation.

Comment: It also still depends on how fast a shutter you are using since a flash is momentary power output and the sun is constant.  If you use a small aperture and a long shutter, then the flash will be hopelessly overpowered.  If you do a very fast shutter, then it will have a better chance of filling the scene.